# UIScrollView contentInset not working

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiscrollview, uikit

I'm having a problem with `contentInset` not working for a UIScrollView to work with a keyboard popup. It *kind of* works: for some reason I need large numbers (maybe above the view's height?) for it to do anything, despite all documentation of `contentInset` showing small numbers like `40.0` (e.g. for a bar), or the keyboard height.

I've reproduced the problem on a brand new application by the following steps:

1. Create new single view application using Xcode new project
2. On storyboard, drag in a scrollview, filling full view size
3. On storyboard, drag in a button, at the very bottom of the screen (inside the scrollview)
4. Link the scrollview to a new property in the ViewController
5. Link button to a method in the ViewController
6. Make the button's pressed method set the contentInset

Here is the code for the ViewController:

```
@interface ViewController ()
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrollView;
@end

@implementation ViewController
- (IBAction)button:(id)sender {
    self.scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, 600, 0.0);
}
@end
```

What am I missing / why do I need large numbers?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Check that *`self.scrollView.contentSize`* is set properly. If *`contentSize.height`* is 0 (as will be the case following your steps), then a large inset is required.

Try adding *`[self.scrollView setContentSize: CGSizeMake(320, 568)];`* to the button method and you'll notice that your inset will now behave as expected.

Comment: Thanks. I had looked at that property before but I didn't realise it gets reset to `{0,0}` after setting `contentInset`. I had to set `contentSize` *after* the inset.

Comment: @Matt I don't work with `UIScrollView` much, but this is interesting. Why would `contentSize` gets reset after setting `contentInset`? So does that mean the logical step would be to always set `contentInset` first then `contentSize`?

Comment: @Unheilig setting *`contentInset`* should not reset *`contentSize`*.

Comment: @Matt Ok, cool. My question was based on the claim by the OP in the first comment above.

Comment: @Unheilig I think what is happening in this case is that placing the UIButton into the UIScrollView is causing Autolayout to set the contentSize to 0. Autolayout seems to take priority over setting contentSize in viewDidLoad.

Answer (score 4):

Matt is right, it has to do with `self.scrollView.contentSize`. I'm using Auto Layout and the missing link for me was explicitly setting the scrollView's `contentSize` property to be the same as my contentView's frame size (contentView is the view inside my scrollView that holds all other views). My contentView is coded to have its size based on the elements I've placed within. They "push out" on the contentView and therefore dynamically drive the contentView's size. It's as a "last step" within `viewDidLayoutSubviews` that I link this dynamic size into `scrollView.contentSize`. Now things work as expected.

```
// Auto Layout Solution
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];
    self.scrollView.contentSize = self.contentView.frame.size;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I just forgot to connect the ScrollView in the Interface Builder...

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue when using auto layout with constraints. Scroll view refused to move with contentInset until I added the following line at the end of keyboardWillShow, then it all worked as expected. As stated above, I suspect that auto layout is resetting contentSize.

```
scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: scrollView.frame.width, height: scrollView.frame.height)
```